# DESKTOP: Running a program with the integrated instead of dedicated GPU

Tags: video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, gpu

I have a desktop with a motherboard that allows me to run a second monitor through the integrated video card and the main monitor through the dedicated one.

The thing is that I also want to run some programs with the integrated card, but all the programs run with the dedicated.

In a laptop I had, with NVIDIA Optimus I had an option to select which programs runs with which card, but now on desktop there's no option.

As I do have right now two video cards, each one managing its own screen, is there a way to run different programs on different cards?

Specs:
OS: Windows 10
Integrated: Intel HD 530
Dedicated: NVIDIA GTX 1070

Answer (score 0):

Just join the Windows Insider program to get the update 17903, which has a built-in Windows functionality to select which GPU to use.

As for today, this is not installed with default Windows.

Tested and working as expected.

Source: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/02/07/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17093-pc/